# Is it possible to do bulk read from redis outside index block in Ruby ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, activeadmin

I have code within `index` block, where if there are X users for a class, the index block is looped X times.

Within `index` block, I make a call to Redis to read a value. So, it would be X calls to Redis.

1. Is there a way to make bulk call to Redis where we can pass X users' ids as an array? (Say `GetBulkUserNames(<Array_Of_X_Users_Ids>)` )
   If yes, how to do that? Should that go in a method or it can be anywhere outside the `index` block?
2. How can we get X users' id within `ActiveAdmin.register` so that we can pass it to `GetBulkUserNames()` ?

Comment: [mre] please. Always need to have a [mre].

Comment: Dunno about your second question but in regards to the first, yes - you can use [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget) (all redis commands have equivalents in the Ruby library)

Answer (score 1):

You can add collection related helpers in the controller. Assuming each X in the collection has a single user_id then something like this, perhaps?

```
controller do
  def cached_user_data
    @data ||= begin
      user_ids = collection.map(&:user_id).uniq
      Hash[user_ids.zip Redis.current.mget(user_ids)]
    end
  end
end

index do
  column :cached_user_data { |x| controller.cached_user_data[x.user_id] }
end
```